# Python Script got ERROR when switch from Windows to Linux

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, cross-platform

I write a Python script on Windows and work pretty well, now I just installed "elementary Os" that is a Ubuntu based distro, but some how when I start the script it just crashed... I dont really now how to fixed it.

I let u a part of the script making problem:

```
memos=open(str(os.getcwd())+'\\LOG\\tres.txt','w')
menf='3)PRESION LATERAL DEL SUELO DE RELLENO\n Ka = '+str(round(Ka,2))+'\nP = '+str(round(P,2))+'\nY = '+str(round(Y,2))+'''
\nHm = '''+str(round(Hm,2))+'\nPm = '+str(round(Pm,2))+'\nYm = '+str(round(Ym,2))
memos.write(menf)
memos.close()
```

So the deal should be...

```
memos=open(str(os.getcwd())+'\\LOG\\tres.txt','w')
```

Because show me an error...

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xba' in position 199: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Now, when I change for...

```
memos=open(str(os.getcwd())+'/LOG/tres.txt','w')
```

It got me another error...

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/jojaror/Documentos/Scripts de Python/LOG/tres.txt'
```

I tryed to solve at my own, but i can't... so, if anyway could help me on this it would be helpful.

Comment: looks like `LOG` directory needs to exist first, case matters on Linux, os.sep would make paths more portable.

Comment: LOG directory already exist...

Comment: Problem solved, ur contribution was useful since "os.sep", then was my Visual Studio Code IDLE making the problem, cuz when I start manually from terminal, everything was good. The problem was OPEN FOLDER option on Visual Studio.